# filtering a php variable

Tags: php, variables

filtering a php variable i wanna limit characters coming from a variable in php simple html dom parser assuming 
`$des = 'lorem ipsum domet lorem ipsum dometlorem ipsum dometlorem ipsum dometlorem ipsum dometlorem ipsum dometlorem ipsum dometlorem ipsum dometlorem ipsum dometlorem ipsum dometlorem;`

but i want to limit this text in a new variable .... so $des will minimized to limited characters like 10 characters. and a new variable like this way>
`$new_des ='lorem ipsu';`
 any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fit the given example:

```
$new_des = substr($des,0,10)
```

If you really mean "words" instead of characters:

```
$new_des = implode(' ', array_slice(str_word_count($des, 1),0,10));
```

Comment: ahh sorry i mean 'characters'

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$new_des = substr($des, 0, 10);
```

First parameter is the string to cut from, the second parameter shows from where to cut (In your case it's 0 which is the start) and the third parameter shows how much of letters to be cut.

Comment: This does not cut down to 10 words, it cuts down to 10 chars.

Comment: In his/her example he is referring letters as words, his/her example of 10 words is showing 10 letter so I thought he/she is needing this ...

Answer (score 0):

10 words, or 10 characters? They would be done in two different ways. 10 characters simply involves the substr function:

```
$new_des = substr($des, 0, 10);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

For 10 words it is a bit more complex. You may want to look into str_word_count, or just simply split by spaces, and reconstruct your sentence from the resulting array:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Answer (score 0):

from CodeIgniter [text helper](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/text_helper.php)

Look also for character_limiter in the same file

```
/**
     * Word Limiter
     *
     * Limits a string to X number of words.
     *
     * @param   string
     * @param   int
     * @param   string  the end character. Usually an ellipsis
     * @return  string
     */
    function word_limiter($str, $limit = 100, $end_char = '&#8230;')
    {
        if (trim($str) === '')
        {
            return $str;
        }

        preg_match('/^\s*+(?:\S++\s*+){1,'.(int) $limit.'}/', $str, $matches);

        if (strlen($str) === strlen($matches[0]))
        {
            $end_char = '';
        }

        return rtrim($matches[0]).$end_char;
    }
```